# How to bind keyboard 'enter' key on Highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, accessibility

I have a Bar-chart created with HighCharts.

I have bound the Click event on my Highcharts chart to lead to a page for the clicked bar:

```
plotOptions: {
        bar:
          series: {
              point: {
                  events: {
                      click: function(e) {
                          const point = e.point;
                          this.goToBackgroundData(point.answerId);
                      }.bind(this)
                  }
              }
          }
```

This works. But when navigating using keyboard and pressing enter on one of the bars, nothing happens. This is a big accessibility issue for non-mouse users.

Is there any way to bind the keyboard 'enter' key to some method, like I have done with 'click'?

Comment: Are you using the accessibility options: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/accessibility? Seems to work with them enabled, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/gj4gc4rk/

Comment: Thanks, seems to work in your jsfiddle. Must be something in the click method I'm using. Will keep troubleshooting.